# Installing a service on a remote machine with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am using powershell 1.0 and I need to install a service on a remote machine and first uninstall it if it exists.

This is my script I have that installs the service, however, I seem unable to uninstall the
service. I have tried installutil however the service path is a network path which installutil, throws errors over.

I'm a complete newbie with powershell, however, I'm sure there must be a better and cleaner way of approaching this.

```
$class = "Win32_Service"
$method = "Create"
$mc = [wmiclass]"\\DUMMYServer\ROOT\CIMV2:$class"
$inparams = $mc.PSBase.GetMethodParameters($method)
$inparams.DesktopInteract = $false
$inparams.DisplayName = "DummyService"
$inparams.ErrorControl = 0
$inparams.LoadOrderGroup = $null
$inparams.LoadOrderGroupDependencies = $null
$inparams.Name = "DummyMessageService"
$inparams.PathName = '\\DummyServer\c$\Applications\DummyMessageWindowsService\DummyWindowsService.exe'
$inparams.ServiceDependencies = $null
$inparams.ServiceType = 16
$inparams.StartMode = "Automatic"
$inparams.StartName = $null # will start as localsystem builtin if null
$inparams.StartPassword = $null

$result = $mc.PSBase.InvokeMethod($method,$inparams,$null)
$result | Format-List
```

Answer (score 0):

try using wmi rather than all the fancy params....  Something like this (untested)

(gwmi win32_service -filter "name='yourservicename'").delete()